# I have no idea how to implement scrollview in android studio! I'm new to this

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I followed all the tutorials and seemingly did the same thing they did but the scrollview format does not change. In all the tutorials I watch, you can see that in the design view, the scrollview was implemented because a shadow thing appears showing the elements which will appear when you scroll. In my design view, though the code is seemingly correct, none of that happens. It's the same thing behaving the same way. **ESSENTIALLY, my problem is that I can't add elements under my existing elements because I run out of space which shouldn't happen because I'm in a scroll view. It is as if my scrollview has not been implemented** Hope that clarifies things. If not I'll upload screenshots.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#23272d"
android:fillViewport="true">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="382dp"
        android:layout_height="213dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/trabago_"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="14dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="382dp"
        android:layout_height="409dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mag"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="288dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="26dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="240dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="240dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="307dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="240dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My Java code is literally the code you get when you start a project. Nothing was touched there yet because I was trying to create a proper design

```
package com.example.practical2;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I have no idea why it does not work. I failed my practical because of this.

Comment: You have a few issues: You're using ConstraintLayout, but none of your views are constrained, so at runtime they will jump to 0,0, you need to read up on that: (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#developer-guide). And, tools:layout_editor_absoluteX/Y is just for the IDE, they won't apply to an actual device, which is why you need constraints. A quick fix is to click the "Infer Constraints" button (the one that looks like a magic wand) above the design view. Also, your view will only scroll if there's something to scroll down to.

Comment: I'm aware that I need to put in constraints. At this point I'm attempting to get the layout in order and whenever I attempt to add another button to go beneath the first button I established, the button refuses to go under it like it would if a scrollview was implemented. That's my main problem.

Comment: That's strange, because I just copied and pasted your code and added an image button with `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="688dp"` to test below yours and it does scroll when I try. Could you share the code that isn't working?